# Minimalist implementation of _bstr_t for Linux

Tags: c++, visual-c++, porting

I have a windows code that I want port to linux.
At one place its using _bstr_t.
I was wondering if there's a minimal _bstr_t port available.
I searched around - but couldn't find one.

The windows code that I want to port is something like this -

```
char **p;
// Malloc and assign some value to *p
_bstr_t str((wchar_t *)*p);
memcpy((char *)*p, (char *)str, len);
```

I searched around and found out that the _bstr_t object has a (char*) operator which returns the string as a single-byte string.
So what I am essentially looking for is a Constriuctor and the (char *) operator overloaded.

Any suggestions as to where I might find any already available port for _bstr_t?
Or any ideas about how I should go ahead implementing this minimal _bstr_t?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a string whose memory management is handled for you, use `std::string` (for `char`-based strings) or `std::wstring` (for `wchar_t`-based strings.)

Is there something specific to the `BSTR` type that you need in Linux? Perhaps a particular API function for which you want an equivalent?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had previously typedef-ed std::wstring to _bstr_t. However, somewhere down the code, GetBSTR is used, and I would need to implement that....

Comment: It appears that BSTR is a Unicode (2 byte chars) string that is used with Microsoft COM. If COM can be done on Linux I would look for the libraries that support it which would likely have BSTR support. If you aren't going to be doing COM then you could look to replace BSTR and _bstr_t with std:wstring or std::string in your code.